# Error connecting to AWS Instance via college proxy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, proxy, ubuntu-14.04

I am not able to connect to my AWS EC2 instance via my college proxy. However it connects when using a non-proxy connection. The error is as follows:

```
$ ssh -i .ssh/aws-key-fast-ai.pem ubuntu@ec2-*----.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com -vvv

OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to ________.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com [34.208.50.122] port 22.
debug1: connect to address *.*.*.* port 22: Connection refused
ssh: connect to host *-*-*-*-*.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com port 22: Connection refused
```

Comment: The error says `Connection refused`. Does it take a long time to fail, or does it fail immediately? If it takes a long time, then the cause is typically that the Security Group settings are not permitting the connection. If it fails immediately, then this suggests that you are using an incorrect username or `.pem` file.

Comment: It fails immediately. It connects perfectly when i am using a non-proxy connection. So how can the .pem file be incorrect?

Comment: Are you connecting from the same computer, with exactly the same command line? That is, absolutely everything is the same except you are using the college proxy? If so, what do you mean by "via my college proxy"? What is different? (eg different network, some configuration somewhere?)

Comment: It is a public proxy that is used by us, the students. And yes I am using exactly the same computer with the same command line.

Comment: What do you change to use the proxy? Do you simply connect to the network and do nothing else? Or do you [configure the proxy settings](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-http-proxy.html)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the answer.

https://wiki.metakgp.org/w/How_to_SSH_into_a_server_that_is_outside_the_campus_network

You have to install corkscrew and follow the procedure listed in the link above. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can access it only if your ip is mentioned under inbound of aws server. When you are using a proxy , IP is getting changed which probably is not mentioned under the inbound.

Comment: It sounds like you are talking about security group settings.  If you are, then this answer is incorrect, because connections not allowed by a security group will never cause a `Connection refused` error.  Security groups do not actively *reject* unauthorized traffic -- they *discard* it.  The error would always be `Connection timed out`.